# Cannot create an Endpoint with Unified Cloud AI Platform custom containers

Tags: google-cloud-platform, tensorflow-serving, google-cloud-ml, google-ai-platform

Because of certain VPC restrictions I am forced to use custom containers for predictions for a model trained on Tensorflow. According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform-unified/docs/predictions/custom-container-requirements) requirements I have created a HTTP server using Tensorflow Serving. The Dockerfile used to `build` the image is as follows:

```
FROM tensorflow/serving:2.4.1-gpu

# copy the model file
ENV MODEL_NAME=my_model
COPY my_model /models/my_model
```

Where `my_model` contains the `saved_model` inside a folder named `1/`.

I have then pushed this image to a Google Container Repository and then created a `Model` by using `Import an existing custom container` and changing the `Port` to 8501. However when trying to deploy the model to an endpoint using a single compute node of type n1-standard-16 and 1 P100 GPU the deployment runs into the below error:

```
Failed to create session: Internal: cudaGetDevice() failed. Status: CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version
```

I am unable to figure how this is happening. I am able to run the same docker image on my local machine and I am able to successfully get predictions by hitting the endpoint that is created: `http://localhost:8501/v1/models/my_model:predict`

Any help is this regard will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to build an image with older gpu tensorflow/serving versions? Does it produce the same error?

Comment: Which one would you suggest?

Comment: How about `tensorflow/serving:2.3.0-gpu/2.2.0-gpu`?

Comment: It seems here is  CUDA driver mismatch issue, maybe downgrading will help?

Comment: Downgrading to `tensorflow/serving:2.3.0-gpu` helped. Thanks!

Comment: @Nick_Kh if you don't mind can you put your comment in as an answer? I can then accept it.

Comment: Great that this was helpful, I've finalized our discovering and posted the answer, hope it will help the others to properly diagnose and fix the similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been solved by downgrading [*Tensorflow serving*](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/guide/serving) image to `2.3.0-gpu` version. According to the error context, the CUDA driver in the custom model image doesn't match the appropriate driver version in GCP AI Platform training cluster.